# Doctrine 2 insists on persisting already managed entity in ManyToOne relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a database table containing departments. I have another table containing people. As you'd expect a department contains many people, and a person is in a single department.

When I want to persist a new person to the database, I create a Person object and try to set it's Department property to an **existing** Department object which is managed by the Entity Manager. However, when I try to persist my new Person, I get an exception:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Entities\Person#department' that was not configured to cascade
>   persist operations for entity:
>   Entities\Department@0000000016abe202000000000d29dd37. To solve this
>   issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown
>   entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping
>   for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

I don't fully understand the part of the exception which says the department is an "unknown entity", since I extracted it via the Entity manager.

As the exception suggests, I inserted a cascade into the yml metadata (`cascade: ["persist"]`). My person then gets saved, but I end up with a **duplicated Department** in the departments table, with a new id.

This must be a very common use case. I've included my code and metadata below. What changes should I make?

Metadata:

```
Entities\Person
  type: entity
  table: people
  fields:
    ...
    departmentId:
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      column: department_id
    ...
  manyToOne:
    department:
      targetEntity: Entities\Department
      joinColumn: department_id
      referenceColumnName: id
```

Code:

```
$department = $em->getRepository('Department')->findOneBy(array('name' => $departmentName);

$person = new Person();
$person->setName('Joe Bloggs');
$person->setDepartment($department);

$em->persist($person);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Just a tip, you can also use `$em->flush($person);` (as of 2.2.x I think) to just flush the `$person` instead of all managed entities, which could potentially (depending on how many entities the EM is manager) be very slow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was caused by using different instances of the Entity Manager to first fetch the department, and then persist the Person.

My entity manager is now a singleton, so whichever class requests an entity manager gets the same instance.